# How to get the files in an array in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have the code in which the JavaScript is written.

The thing which I want is whenever I click on the button that the file manager will open up which will allow me to choose the file and I want to append those files in an array.

The following code looks like this:

```
const [fileNames, setFileNames] = useState([]);
const handleFiles = (e) => {
    [...e.target.files].forEach(file => {
        console.log("file >>> ", file);
        
        setFileNames([...file]);
       
    });
}

return(
    <input type="file" id="selectedFile" style={{ display: 'none' }} onChange={handleFiles} />
)
```

How to get the files in an array?

Comment: may be this would help you - [link](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-implement-multiple-file-uploads-in-react-4cdcaadd0f6e)

Answer (score 0):

**There was no needed steps in your code.**
Here something that works exacly like you want it to.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  function handleChange(e) {
    setFiles([...e.target.files]);
  }
  function handleLogFile(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(files);
    //do something else with the files
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleLogFile}>
        <input type="file" multiple onChange={handleChange} />
        <button>Log the files</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```